# Rasterize point layer error in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, rasterization, gdal-rasterize

[image]

[image]

As advised, I have reprojected the point layer (Project CRS- WGS84 EPSG: 4326) and then trying to rasterize (Vector to raster) the point layer using different combination of pixel and georeferenced units of output raster size but it is not working. Mostly it is not converting in some case even if it converts into raster then it is either not showing on the window or showing in one solid colour strip. Please refer attached images for input information.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. While images can be useful to clarify a problem, they are not legible on all devices and cannot be searched by others with the same issue. Questions *must* have a problem statement, in English, which describes the environment, data, task, and problem. Without these the question is likely to be closed.

Comment: As advised, i have reprojected the point layer (Project CRS- WGS84 EPSG: 4326) and then trying to rasterize (Vector to raster) the point layer using different combination of pixel and groreferenced units of output raster size but it is not working. mostly it is not converting in some case even if it converts into raster then it is either not showing on the window or showing in one solid color strip. Please advise.

Comment: I dont see any errors in your screenshot or text

Answer (score 1):

**The Problem**

Your layer is in CRS `EPSG:4326` with units in degrees. The `Width/Horizontal resolution` is set to `500`, meaning 500 degrees - whereas the whole world has an extent of 360 degrees. Thus it is way too much. Same is true for `Height/Vertical resolution`.

**The solution**

First [reproject](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html?#reproject-layer) your layer to a projected CRS that fits your area of interest (see next point), then rasterize this layer. [See also this for reprojection](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/training_manual/processing/crs.html?). Projected CRS have units in meters (or other similar length units, not degrees).

*Be aware: in your screenshot, you have an output resolution of 500x500 pixels. If the extent of your area of interest is not a square, but has the shape of a rectangle (as in your case), with this settings the pixels will be in rectangular shape: the whole extent will be divided to 500 pixels width, 500 pixels hight. That's probably not what you want, you want square-shaped pixels of a certain size. Thus change `Output raster size units` to `Georeferenced units`. Like this, `500 x 500` means 500 m x 500 m and the pixels will appear as squares.*

**How to find an appropriate CRS**

The coordinate values of the output extent tell me that your area of intereset if a relatively small region in northern India, east of New Delhi. Using the site [What UTM zone am I in?](https://mangomap.com/robertyoung/maps/69585/what-utm-zone-am-i-in-#), you see that this area corresponds to `UTM Zone: 44`. That corresponds to EPSG-code `32644`.

*Screenshot, showing how to reproject:*
[image]

Comment: As advised, i have reprojected the point layer (Project CRS- WGS84 EPSG: 4326) and then trying to rasterize (Vector to raster) the point layer using different combination of pixel and groreferenced units of output raster size but it is not working. mostly it is not converting in some case even if it converts into raster then it is either not showing on the window or showing in one solid color strip. Please advise.

Comment: Easiest would be if you can share your data for testing